# Not enough space to show ad (AdMob)

Tags: android, layout, admob

I am trying to show [AdMob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdMob) ads in my activity, but it is always giving error that "not enough space to show ad".

My XML file is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adMobadView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admobid"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java file:

```
    AdView ad=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adMobadView);

    AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
    re.setTesting(true);
    re.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.FEMALE);
    ad.loadAd(re);
```

[LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file):

```
   02-18 14:16:17.869: W/webcore(813): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
   02-18 14:16:17.979: I/Ads(813): onReceiveAd()
   02-18 14:16:17.979: W/Ads(813): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <320, 50>, Has: <288, 430>
```

Comment: Try setting the width to match_parent and height to wrap_content in your "com.google.ads.AdView" Ad View. Just check!

Comment: Are you using dialog theme for activity in Manifest file.

Comment: just place your AdView inside linear layout. i give an example below.. you can try

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The left and right padding of your RelativeLayout is consuming space required by your AdView.

Change RelativeLayout config to :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 ...
 android:paddingLeft="0dp"
 android:paddingRight="0dp"
 ...
>
```

You probably also want to change your AdView config to:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adMobadView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        />
```

as you don't really want your AdView to consume the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check the dimensions of the screen and the paddings, and see if it actualy fits.

Also, try to change the Adview to this:

```
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adMobadView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admobid"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to show ads inside relative layout you can follow this design

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutpopular"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutadd"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        >
            <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="3dp">
         <com.google.ads.AdView
             xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
             android:id="@+id/adView"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:background="#2d2f2f"
            ads:adUnitId="admobId" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with NativeExpressAdView. If you add padding or margin to your layout, I think, it's not a good idea to fix the ad's size width. I sugger to do in programmatically

1. First step : get the dp size of screen witdh

   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
               //float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
                dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

2. Second step:

mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize((int) dpWidth, 150));

Answer (score -1):

Simply set the margins to 0dp in res->values->dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Well spotted sir! In my case this was the error as well. It does not like margins the piece of crap!