# Can not see add from admob hello world android program

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, ads

This is my main class -

```
package com.example.trial;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adview = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adrequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adview.loadAd(adrequest);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.trial.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   ads:adSize="BANNER"
                   ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-00000000000000000/1111111111"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ANother file I modified is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trial"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"   
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

I have added google-play-services_lib properly in my project buildpath.
Project in eclipse shows no error as such. But It is not showing ad after running app.
Internet connection is proper (Checked by running browser on android emulator)

Can someone suggest what might have gone wrong ?

I am new to admob. I have created ad unit default setting and using its id. Is there anything else to be done ??

update - when I removed these two lines

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

It showed error in box where ad is supposed to be placed. That means view has been created ??

Comment: Post your logcat. It will show the ad request and response. Also post the image of the error you see in place of your ad.

Answer (score 0):

Enabled logcat from here - 
[How to enable LogCat/Console in Eclipse for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android)

Solved problem using this - 
[Not enough space to show ad (AdMob)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848532/not-enough-space-to-show-ad-admob)

Thanks @William !!!