# Android Admob ad not visible

Tags: android

I have added all required code but admob ad is not visible neither on emulator nor on my device. I have created Admob account today itself, is it the reason why i am not able to see add?
The ad part is completely blank while running the app.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
            .addTestDevice("MyDeviceId_1").addTestDevice("MyDeviceId")  // An example device ID
            .build();
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: apply width as match_parent, if still not visible try giving heigh as 50dp. Where have you assigned ad id to admob request?

Answer (score 1):

remove these lines from your root layout

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

if your `AdView` will not get full width of your screen, it will not be visible

Also you need to load ad in your AdView

```
adView.loadAd(request);
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848532/not-enough-space-to-show-ad-admob)

Answer (score 1):

For load & show the Admob banner add need to more space .Don't get more space to  show  on Admob banner add for declaration your root layout(RelativeLayout).Please remove those two line..

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Must be you need to add this line on your java code.

```
adView.loadAd(request);
```

I don't able to show this line on your code.Are you add this line.Please check this.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to add Internet permission to your manifest. Check RRR's answer too.