# Admob native ads is not showing even if onAdLoaded is firing

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I have integrated `Admob` native ads. I have used same adUnitId in multiple screen to load native ads. In most of the screen my code is working fine but in some screen `onAdLoaded` overridden method is calling but ads is not displaying.
I am using below code to native ads.

```
 nativeExpressAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                    nativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                    super.onAdLeftApplication();
                    nativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    nativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


nativeExpressAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                nativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

View of `Nativeexpressview`

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/nativeExpressAdView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:adSize="300x250"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_margin"
    app:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"/>
```

`onAdLoaded()` method is firing but ads is not loading. Can any one pls help me to identify the issue.

Comment: you must be getting some error in your logs, check closely. I also faced similar issues recently which was due to network error

Comment: I didn't see any error in logs. Could you pls tell me how you resolved the similar issue.

Comment: Check that the View has enough space to be displayed. In your case, the parent container must be at least 300dp wide and 250dp high.
Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848532/not-enough-space-to-show-ad-admob

Comment: Thanks buddy issue was with view size. I have resolved issue for some screen and working on for rest.

Answer (score -1):

After you show an add always bring the banner to front
nativeExpressAdView.bringToFront()
I do that in onresume as well.

Comment: Why the downvote, please explain? How about your screen is Frame, Relative, Coordinator or similar Layout and you have dinamically changed views? How about you have a view/s on top of your ad?